# How to make use handover protocol to pass control from dialogflow bot to facebook inbox?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I want to pass control from my dialog flow bot to facebook inbox. I have set dialog flow as the primary receiver and page inbox as secondary. I have connected dialog flow-fb using one-click integration. When a certain intent is identified I make the pass thread control call using the webhook connected to dialog flow fulfillment.

But I'm getting this error:

(#10) Only available to Primary and Secondary Receivers

Any way to figure this out?

Below is the webhook call i make

```
app.post('/', function(request, response){
    const psid = 
    request.body.originalDetectIntentRequest.payload.data.sender.id
    var request = require("request");
    var options = { 
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/pass_thread_control',
        qs: { access_token: 'access_token' },
        headers: 
            {
                'cache-control': 'no-cache',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
        body: 
            { 
                recipient: { id: psid },
                target_app_id: 263902037430900,
                metadata: 'String to pass to secondary receiver app' },
                json: true
            };
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);

    console.log(body);
});

});
```

Comment: But can we do this in the response json from the dialogflow fulfillment? Something in the platform specific payload?